# Whenever I use isLocked property of LockablePivot , it throws exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, pivot, silverlight-toolkit

I'm simply using  `WP Toolkit`'s `LockablePivot` , until there everything is fine , but if I define `isLocked` property in `XAML` file, it throws `NullReferenceException`  in `InitializeComponent` method in the  `g.i.cs` file.

If i use

```
myPivot.isLocked=true
```

in code behind, it throws `NullReferenceException` -again- the line after it. I couldn't find anything to solve this, any ideas?

Here's the stack trace of NullReferenceException:

```
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LockablePivot.CreateAnimationInformation()
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LockablePivot.FadeOutHeaders()
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LockablePivot.OnIsLockedChanged(Boolean newValue)
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LockablePivot.OnIsLockedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChngeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LockablePivot.set_IsLocked(Boolean value)
at enVisionMobile.DocumentPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated(Object content, Uri uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean isNavigationInitiator, PhoneApplicationPage existingContentPage, PhoneApplicationPage newContentPage)
at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject content, NavigationMode mode)
at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginLoad>b__0(Object args)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

When I first set the isLocked property, nothing seems wrong.
[image: first]

When I run the debug build, it throws this exception.
[image: second]

And after closing debug:
[image: third]

[image: forth]

When I delete isLocked setter from XAML, and instead set it on code behind(this one's stack trace is the same):

[image: fifth]

Comment: I don't believe you.  But you can prove me a liar if you [edit] and add the full exception details to your question.  These can be found by using the "copy exception detail to the clipboard" link on the exception assistant dialog, or by calling ToString on the exception if you can catch it.  This is the first step when debugging NREs, and in fact *any* exception.

Comment: Okay, I will take a few pictures then @Will

Comment: You take a picture and I'll VTC this as a dupe of the canonical NRE-debugging question.  Seriously.  There is nothing more useless than a picture of an exception message.  I gave you all the directions you need in my comment.  Please follow them, for the sanity of everyone here!

Comment: @Will man, take it easy. I was about to do both. I explained the ways I'm getting error. I edited the question.

Comment: I HAET EXCEPTION PICTURS!  Lemme see if there's anything obviously wrong..

Comment: Where's the control labeled LayoutRoot?

Comment: it's just the parent of all contents. the pivot is the grandchild of LayoutRoot.

Comment: I don't see the control here http://phone.codeplex.com/ so I can't see if there is anything obvious in the code.  Where did you get this?  It very well could be just a bug in the toolkit.  Whenever I get in a situ like this, I download the code, add it as a project reference rather than a (nuget package?) binary reference, then debug through it.  That's not much of an answer, but that'll give you some insight into why it is happening...

Comment: @Will I don't need the LockablePivot anymore. But I'm curious what was the problem. Lemme know if you find something. I'm looking for what's wrong, too.

Comment: By the way, I tried from in another project which I created now, but the same exception occurs.

Comment: @Will I'll try adding as project reference.

Comment: Where did you get the control that's throwing the exception?

Comment: @will Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit if I understand what you mean.

Comment: Where?  Did you find it under a dusty magazine in a closet?  Nuget?  Some SDK?  I can't find the control you're talking about in the current codebase of the toolkit.

Comment: @Will current toolkit is for wp8, and they did extract lockablepivot from it because wp8 pivot has isLocked property. I'm using 2011 release for wp7.

Comment: Code is here http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/WindowsPhone71/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/Pivot/LockablePivot.cs looking for something obvious on the code path...

Comment: Wild-ass guess based on source... Add a TranslateTransform to headers that does nothing.  You might have to create a style that does this.  That's the only thing in CreateAnimationInformation that might possibly result in a NRE.  If the line `_animInfo[i].transform = TransformAnimator.GetTranslateTransform(headerItem);` returns a null, the next line might throw an NRE, but the line after that definitely will.  Other than that, all I can suggest is pull down the project, add it to your solution, and debug it :/